# Is there a word that means something along the line of "add information in order to clarify what really happened"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means something along the line of "add information in order to clarify what really happened"? Sometimes, someone tells the truth, but they omit to mention relevant details in order to build a narrative for their political gains? What's the action of doing the opposite and making sure important information aren't omitted in a discussion? Is there a verb or a phrase that means exactly that? I looked up "precise" and couldn't find any relevant word, and precise is a bit too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like *[expand on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/expand-on-sth)*

```
to give more details about something you have said or written:
```

> "We're going to cut taxes and lower the deficit"
>
> "Sorry, can you **expand on** that? How?"

Answer (score 1):

The first phrase that entered my mind is **in detail**.

This two-word phrase gets its own definition in several dictionaries, such as Oxford, M-W, Wordnik, and Cambridge:

> [**in detail**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in_detail) (*phrase*) 
>   As regards every feature or aspect; fully.
>   *We will have to examine the proposals in detail.*
>
> [**in detail**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20detail) with all the particulars
>   *explained the job in detail*
>
> [**in detail**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/in%20detail) (*adverb, idiomatic*) thoroughly (including all important particulars); including every detail
>
> [**in detail**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/detail?q=detail_1) including or considering all the information about something or every part of something

You could use this phrase in a sentence like:

> You need to tell us what happened in detail.

which would mean:

> You need to provide all the information necessary to clarify what really happened.

which is something along the lines of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best single verb I can think of is [**elucidate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidate):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *transitive verb*
>   : to make lucid especially by explanation or analysis
>   // *elucidate* a text
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   : to give a clarifying explanation

The most common instruction to somebody in this context is:

> Please *elucidate*.